# Vigenere python - substring not found error

Tags: python, keyword, vigenere

This code works up until line 31. Then the error 
`ciphercharindexvalue = alphabet.index(keylist[keyincrement]) + alphabet.index(plaintext)
ValueError: substring not found` 
appears. 
I am unsure why this is happening, could you help me please?
I am trying to encrypt the code using a key word in this code. I am able to encrypt with a number [as seen at the beginning] but I would now like to use a keyword to create a "Vigenere cipher".

This is the full code:

```
eord = input("Would you like to encrypt or decrypt? [e/d]: ")
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ012346789"
string = ''

if eord == 'e':
    texte = input ("Type your word to encrypt: ")
    key1 = int(input("Choose a key: "))
    for letter in texte:
        number = (ord(letter)) + (key1)
        letter = (chr(number))
        string = (str(string)) + (str(letter))
    print (string)
    keyword = input ("Would you like to encrypt your code further? [Y/N]: ")



    if keyword == "Y" or "y":
        plaintext = input("Please enter plain text: ")
        key = input("Please enter a keyword: ")
        keylist = []
        keylength = 0
        while keylength < len(plaintext):
            for char in  key:
                if keylength < len(plaintext):
                    keylist.append(str(char))
                    keylength = keylength + 1
        completeciphertext = []
        ciphercharindexvalue = 0
        keyincrement = 0
        for plaintextchar in plaintext:
            ciphercharindexvalue = alphabet.index(keylist[keyincrement]) + alphabet.index(plaintext)
            while ciphercharindexvalue >25:
                ciphercharindexvalue = ciphercharindexvalue - 26
            completeciphertext.append(alphabet[ciphercharindexvalue])
            keyincrement = keyincrement + 1
        print (''.join(completecipertext))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to get the index of plaintext instead of plaintextchar.  Perhaps this will work:

```
ciphercharindexvalue = alphabet.index(keylist[keyincrement]) + alphabet.index(plaintextchar)
```